# Increase number of lines in GDB live disassembly

Tags: linux, gdb

Is it possible to increase the number of auto disassembled lines that `GDB` (with `pwndbg`) shows when stepping through an executable? I have tried using `display x $pc` but it doesn't fit in with the rest of the debugger.

Currently looks like:

[image: Currently looks like]

Ideally would look like this(Except functional):

[image: Ideally would look like this(Except functional)]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`winheight` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html#index-winheight).  This should increase the size of the disassembly by twenty lines:

```
winheight asm +20
```